# Search with full name instead of just first name or last name

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am developing an API built with PHP and Codeigniter and I use MySQL as database.

I have a user table called Users which contains the following columns:

```
- ID
- Firstname
- Lastname
- Email
```

How can a user search this table using a full name? For example it works fine to search either by Martin or Smith, but not Martin Smith.

This is the query I am using now:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('firstname', $args['query']);
$this->db->or_like('lastname', $args['query']);
```

**Update**

If I use this query as suggested below I cannot find anything. Not with full name, first name or last name. Then both first name AND last name needs to be the same word.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('firstname', $args['query']);
$this->db->like('lastname', $args['query']);
```

Comment: Why doesnt it work? What do you expect, what happens instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight out of my head, but what about

```
$input = 'Martin Smith';

$names = explode($input);

$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('users'); 
$this->db->where_in('firstname', $names); 
$this->db->or_where_in('lastname', $names);
```

Should output something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE firstname IN ('Martin', 'Smith') 
OR lastname IN ('Martin', 'Smith')
```

Comment: Good idea but I will not work with names like Abraham van Helsing or Jonathan Parker Bowles.

Comment: +1 for name reference. Perhaps not the most flexible solution but: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) = "$input_firstname $input_lastname";`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('firstname', $args['first_name']);
$this->db->like('lastname', $args['last_name']);
```

This results in:

```
Select * from users
WHERE firstname LIKE '%first_name%' 
AND lastname LIKE '%last_name%
```

Comment: Well, if I do that the search does not work. Please see update.

Comment: The problem is that if I do a search for "martin smith" it will not find anything, not with martin either since it is then looking for a user with first name martin and last name martin.

Comment: You could put the full function and value of the parameters that are representative of actual use?

Answer (score 0):

Change :`$this->db->or_like('lastname', $args['query']);`

To:     `$this->db->like('lastname', $args['query']);`

Comment: Well, if I do that the search does not work. Please see update.

Comment: miss that, you should use 'query1' and 'query2' or something like that... otherwise it will use the same parameter to search both fields..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that OR for an AND:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Firstname = '$firstname' AND Lastname = '$lastname'
```

Comment: Well, if I do that the search does not work. Please see update.

Comment: Ok, I eddited it.

NOTE: MySql is case sensitive you say your columns are named Firstname, Lastname, Email but in your query you are using them like firstname and lastname

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this and working fine for me:

```
$terms = explode(' ', $searchtxtusername); 
if(count($terms)>1){
    $this->db->like('u.first_name', $this->db->escape_like_str($terms[0]));
    $this->db->like('u.last_name', $this->db->escape_like_str($terms[1]));
}else{
    $this->db->like('u.first_name', $this->db->escape_like_str($terms[0]));
    $this->db->or_like('u.last_name', $this->db->escape_like_str($terms[0]));
}
```

Here, $searchtxtusername is the search term including first name and last name (space separated). If there is only one term, then it checks the same term for both first name and last name.

Example: if I searched for Bob, then search condition is like:

```
first_name LIKE '%Bob%' 
AND last_name LIKE '%Bob%'
```

and if I searched for Bob Beggins, then search condition becomes:

```
first_name LIKE '%Bob%' 
AND last_name LIKE '%Beggins%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
if($data['keyword'] != ''){
   $this->db->like('CONCAT(First_Name, " ", Last_Name," ")', $data['keyword']);
}
```